# When looking at other dev's javascript code, i often see a JSON object/fn getting used to parse JSON? Where does this object come from?

Tags: javascript, json

The object/fn used below is I presume is coming from global scope, what creates this object?

```
      function setup_log() {
        $("pre.code.json").attr("title", "click to inspect in browser debugger: console.log()");
        $("pre.code.json").css("cursor", "pointer");
        $("pre.code.json").click(function(){
          var code = $(this).find("code");
          console.log(code.html());
          console.log(JSON.parse(code.html()));
        });
      }
```

Comment: From the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON. It's also part of the JS spec.

Comment: You mean JSON.parse? that's part of javascript.

Comment: this is a good question, it is just phrased badly.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON object is a part of the implementation of the Javascript language, in most modern web browsers. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Be aware that earlier browsers do not support this object. The above link has a list of supported versions. Basically, IE7 and below are the worst offenders.

Comment: Thanks Felix, comment removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a built in function that the JavaScript provides.  For a list of supported browsers you can use http://caniuse.com/#feat=json

Comment: See comment on @wicker95's answer. JSON is not provided by JavaScript. It's provided by certain (most) *implementations* of JS. It's no more part of "JavaScript" than `document.getElementById`, another interface provided by certain JS implementations.

Comment: This is more what I was looking for. Sorry for the poor wording of my question. What decides the implantation of js available on the window? Just the browser?